# iOS Facebook add hashtag to Open Graph Stories

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, facebook-graph-api, hashtag

How is it possible to add a hashtag to the share dialog in iOS?

I'am using the FacebookSDK share dialog and creating a story like this

```
[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction:leaveAction
                                      actionType:@"..."
                             previewPropertyName:@"..."
                                         handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {...}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Unfortunately, there's no hashtag support for share dialog.